# Chrome Extension: Inject script on Dom loaded

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension. Actually I'm injecting some scripts on page load event, but it causes an ugly behavior (I'm deleting some elements). For this reason I want to inject some of the script just after the DOM load, years ago I was able to do that but now it's impossible for me.

Do you know if it is possible in the current version and how to do that?

EDIT:

This is my current code:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,{'file':'onLoad.js'});  
    }
});
```

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please create and post a [minimal, complete and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example...
Its hard to guess what you are trying to do and what is the error...

Comment: At the very least, explain what you mean by ugly behavior - and why you can't replicate what you did years ago.

Comment: Hi. It's quite simple, I'm removing some elements from the page, as it is done after the load you can see the element disappearing after some seconds changing the layout in the webpage, so I want to do that before rendering the elements, just after the DOM load.

I was able to do that before Chrome changed the extensions politics and the way you capture events in tabs and inject scripts.

Comment: @Iskariote, what you do you mean when you are saying "before rendering the elements but after the DOM load"? Do you mean the DOM is complete but subresources like images and others are not?

Comment: Hi all, I edited the description to add my actual code. @HaibaraAi, indeed I 'm referencing the elements in DOM, I have a selector previously  saved and I want to remove the element from DOM before loading any resource.

Comment: Why do you use programmatic injection and not manifest-defined injection?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your intent

> I want to remove the element from DOM before loading any resource

You can take a look at [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and refer to `run_at` part. You could set `"run_at": "document_end"` which will ensure your code is injected after the DOM is complete but before any other resources have loaded.

> In the case of "document_end", the files are injected immediately after the DOM is complete, **but before subresources like images and frames have loaded**.

Comment: Note that injecting at `changeInfo.status === 'complete'` will negate this in any case, as it fires after subresources load.

Comment: @Xan, so I just recommend to do this via `manifest.json` not inject through the code.

Comment: It depends on why programmatic injection was used in the first place. If the snippet in the question is actual, non-trimmed code, then of course manifest-based solution is better. Otherwise, one needs to mention that status "complete" is too late to do anything.

Comment: @Xan, any document about the precise definition of "loading" and "complete"?

Comment: Sadly, no. [The enum](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-TabStatus), [the event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated). Empirically, this is fired when Chrome replaces the spinner with the favicon (which happens, I think, after `window.onload`)